# Why doesn't linear resistance scale proportionally with the square of length?

Tags: resistors, resistance, theory

I have an in depth question about basic proportionality of resistance. Why doesn't it scale with the square of length? I ask this because what is causing the potential difference on two leads is charged electric fields at each lead, which decrease with the square of distance.

Answer (score 5):

You are confusing several basic concepts.  The E field of two point charges in a 3 dimensional space follows a \$ \frac{1}{r^2}\$ relationship.  If instead to two point charges, you use two infinitely long wires running parallel to each other the field is proportional to \$\frac{1}{r}\$.  So the dimensionality really matters. In a resistor there is one path, if you double the length of the path it will take twice as long. The electric field is confined to the interior of the resistor.

Comment: Your answer is well-upvoted, so that's a good sign. Here's a question: your analogy is insightful, but perhaps we both understand that truly there are no lines of charge between two leads of a battery driving with force. Unfortunately, I'm not quite convinced that in the wire the entirety of our electric field is sapped up isn't it true that all the electric field propogates throughout all space? All the wire does is permit. I'm not sure why I can ignore this fact here, but thanks

Comment: I understand that there are no lines of charge, because lines of charge do not exist.  The electric field exists within the resistor because there is a potential difference.  There will be an electric field outside of the resistor, which need not be considered as it is not involved with the conduction _through_ the resistor.

Comment: I see. We needn't ignore that idea, but it is true that while the outside field does work initially to start the proces, the final field is a product of this and irregular charge buildups caused by the uneven fields. At the end of the day, electricity is all about balance, right?

Answer (score 2):

Your initial premise is incorrect. This is what the [electric field lines](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/estatics/Lesson-4/Electric-Field-Lines) between two oppositely charged points in free space looks like:

[image]

In the case of a resistive material that is much higher in conductivity than the surrounding air or whatever, the equipotential surfaces will be equally-spaced planes passing through the block of material perpendicular to the direction of current flow, so the field is uniform volts-per-m from one end to the other.

Comment: I simply don't understand your answer. What physical object is described by the term "equipotential surfaces?" Where did they come from? I have a lack of understanding of this technical terminology. @Spehro Pefhany thanks tho

Comment: Imagine joining together all the points where the potential is equal. Say the two nodes are at -1V and +1V. At -0.5V, 0V and +0.5V there will be a 3D surface where the potential is the same. In the case of a single charge you could say they're concentric spheres of non-equal spacing.

Comment: By `"so the field is uniform volts-per-m from one end to the other"` do you rather mean `"so the field *degrades* uniformly from one end to the other"`?

Comment: Thank you for explaining yourself. I assume that you understand that the potential energy of a point charge at one node is zero, whereas the potential energy of a point charge at another node is positive and non-zero. A negative voltage is therfore weird to assume. I am still stewing on your answer, thanks.

Comment: @sherrellbc I would actually want the field to degrade linearly with distance, to match the linear proportionality of resistance, but this cannot be held. If this were true, some parts of the wire would be more affected and thus move fastly in respect to other portions. Current would be different based on the cross section of the wire, and we would effectively own capacitating wires since the earlier portions of the wire would have more electrons than the latter half, thus making a charge buildup

Comment: @sherrellbc The field would have uniform volts per meter. The voltage potential is what degrades when moving through it. You'd have to have an interestingly doped semiconductor to have a linearly degraded e-field within it.

Comment: @horta, well that is even more interesting to me that it is not a linear effect. How does the field degrade across a simple device, like a diode, for example? Namely, if I were to somehow measure the voltage from anode to cathode in small increments across the semiconductor?

Comment: @sherrellbc actually it's not a terribly interesting doping profile. It's just uniformly doped. See here for an example:
http://ecee.colorado.edu/~bart/book/book/chapter4/ch4_3.htm
It is a linearly degraded field within a PN junction.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a physicist, but an intuitive explanation might be:

The electric field in free space (or in homogeneous media) decreases with the square of distance, as it spreads out over concentric spherical areas.

The electric field in a wire is substantially confined to the wire, and so the 'surface area' of the field does not increase as the square of distance.

Comment: I like your answer in that it involves creative thought. However, I'm not convinced that the electric field is confined to a wire, in that there is no electric field outside of the wire, this just seems to be wrong. Maybe I'm wrong. I like your answer though, as it 'works out' in that it would explain the linear proportionality going on.

Comment: Actually you are *almost* wrong: there is a little EF outside the wire but that's negligible. That's whe whole point of using wires, EF really likes going into them instead of free air, at least at low (some 10's of MHz) frequencies.

Comment: An interesting comment @VladimirCravero. You see, what I thought it was was that the electric field penetrates to everywhere, but everywhere responds differently based on what part of 'everywhere' we're looking at. Air, for example, doesn't create dipoles nearly as well as metal.

Comment: Well that's exactly what I meant, only add frequency in the pit and know that "the higher the frequency, the higher the penetration"

Comment: Hoho, sounds good. @VladimirCravero

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permittivity have a look at the "complex permittivity" part

Comment: @VladimirCravero, At frequencies > 10MHz is that where we begin to radiate signifcantly? Any suggested literature?

Comment: That was just a shot in the dark, with the right antenna carriers as low as 100's Hz can be used (submarine LF radios). I am sorry but this topic is quite vast and I am not an expert, and a question about "where to study" something is not in topic at all on this site. You should search some forum about electronics and ask there.